# SqlBulkCopy - empty datarows in db2table

Tags: c#, csv, sqlbulkcopy

now I finally got to write the rows of my csv (somewhat) into the table. It does add the 7 rows of the csv, but without data. The only thing it sets is the id, but that's autoincremented anyways. The data out of the csv doesn't arrive in the table.

```
 static DataTable GetDataTableFromCsv(string path, bool isFirstRowHeader, string csvSelection)
        {
            string header= isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";

            string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
            List<string> headerList = getHeader(fileName);
            string sql = @"SELECT " + "*" + " FROM [" + fileName + "]";
            //string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" +  fileName  + "];";

            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + headerList + ";FMT=Delimited(;)\""))
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
            {
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                foreach (var item in headerList)
                {
                    dataTable.Columns.Add(item);
                }

                adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                writeSchema(dataTable.Columns, pathOnly, fileName);
                return dataTable;
            }

        }

public static Boolean BatchBulkCopy(DataTable dt, string destTable, List<string> columnMapping, IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection connection, int batchSize)
        {
            DataTable dtInsertRows = dt;
            using (IBM.Data.DB2.DB2BulkCopy sbc = new IBM.Data.DB2.DB2BulkCopy(connection, IBM.Data.DB2.DB2BulkCopyOptions.TableLock))
            {
                sbc.DestinationTableName = "\"" + destTable + "\"";

                foreach (var mapping in columnMapping)
                {
                    var split = mapping.Split(new[] { ',' });
                    sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("\"" + split.First() + "\"", "\"" + split.Last() + "\"");
                }
                try{
                    sbc.WriteToServer(dtInsertRows);
                    sbc.Close();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
            return false;
        }
private static void writeSchema(DataColumnCollection columns, string csvDir, string csvFileName)
        {
            FileStream fsOutput =
                     new FileStream(csvDir + "\\schema.ini",
                                         FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter srOutput = new StreamWriter(fsOutput);

            srOutput.WriteLine("[" + csvFileName + "]");
            int i = 1;
            foreach (DataColumn item in columns)
            {
                srOutput.WriteLine("Col" + i + "=\"" + item.ToString() + "\" Text");
                i++;
            }
            srOutput.Close();
            fsOutput.Close();
        }

        private static List<string> getHeader(string fileName)
        {
            string fullpath = @ImportPath + "\\" + fileName;
            List<string> header = new List<string>();
            var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fullpath));

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(';');

                foreach (var spalte in values)
                {
                    header.Add(spalte);
                }
                reader.Close();
                return header;
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your sbc.ColumnMappings. I think it is just needed if your datatable did not reflect the structure of your db2 table. In my code I process the datatable to have the same number and order of columns as the DB2 table. I don`t use ColumnMappings.

2nd: your sbc.DestinationTableName. I use here a string with the exact schema and tablename from DB2. DestinationTableName = "DB2-Schema.DB2-Tablename"

Answer (score 0):

What version is the DB2 running on? Bulkcopy is supported from version 9.7